# Is there a way to apply syntax highlighting to the results of :g?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, global-command

I do a lot of work with log files, and I use a lot of `hi def foo` and `syn match foo` in my .vimrc.  Is there a way to apply that syntax formatting to the results of a :g command?

Comment: Welcome to vi SE. What's the goal are you trying to achieve? What would solve your problem? Maybe there are other ways to do it.

Comment: No. This is not possible.

Comment: @Friedrich I have some pretty big log files, so ideally I'd like to reduce what is displayed to lines that match a substring, typically something like {38} (curly brackets included), and have those lines display the syntax formatting already in .vimrc.

Ideally if I could add the line immediately following a match as well that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `:g` command, you may instead want to use a fold-expression and fold-away non-matching lines. Because in this case, you will keep the syntax highlighting, for the non-folded lines.

Something like this should work:

```
:set foldenable foldmethod=expr foldminlines=0 foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)!~@/
```

You can map this to a custom key-mapping or use a custom ex-command for this.

It will get a bit complicated, if you want to keep adding new patterns for the fold expression, so that you can keep adding patterns to be folded away.

My [csv](https://github.com/chrisbra/csv.vim) plugin does this, essentially by defining a stack of patterns and dynamically adding or removing patterns from it so that it can move away non-matching lines (see [here](https://github.com/chrisbra/csv.vim/blob/master/autoload/csv.vim#L1774-L1847)).